# How do I find posts?

Tags: database

I am a new website administrator and I am having issues with posts not showing on dashboard.  Posts   All(21) Published (13) Pending (8).  This is a listing site and the posts used to show up.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit where/what you expect to appear? Screenshots are helpful when talking about interface issues.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting your question, it could use some more detail, but I think the old site must have had a plugin installed. Posts and their statuses are not displayed in any of the default WordPress dashboard widgets.

The only two plugins that I know that do something like that are [Post Status Menu Items](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-status-menu-items/)—by pure coincidence, I'm the author of that plugin—and [EditFlow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-flow/). I've included a screenshot of those two side-by-side, respectively.

[image: Two WordPress Dashboard Widgets displaying post statuses.]

Comment: I hope this works.  The two posts that show up are only test posts created by the administrator.Screen Shot 2013-05-08 at 1.21.01 PM

Comment: User posts don't show up on dashboard but two admin posts appear.Screen Shot 2013-05-08 at 1.29.52 PM

Comment: Neither screenshot came through. Please update your original question (with a screenshot!).

Comment: I uploaded EditFlow and the Dashboard, Posts reads: All(29) Published (15) Pending Review (14)

Comment: When I click on Pending Review(14), I get No Posts found. Why can't I access these posts as the administrator?

Comment: If this answer got the links you were missing to show up, then it answered your question. If so, you need to accept this answer and open a new question. If this didn't answer your question, then you need to revise your question and clarify what you're trying to do and what you have already done.

Comment: If you accept an answer (meaning it answers the question you were asking) then you need to click the check mark next to the answer).